# Azure redis cache for caching secrets

Tags: azure, security, distributed-caching, azure-redis-cache, distributed-cache

I wanted to know what is the recommended way to cache and access secrets in distributed setup with service fabric backing our applications and services. Storing secrets in key vault is a known thing, but a distributed cache solution will help with latency requirement. Redis Cache seems like a viable candidate. Has any one used it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Azure Redis cache is a Azure in memory database used for faster retrieval and performance. But you can store data into it only in key,Value pair format.

It will complete your latency requirement but you have go through more details for Encryption of your data as it will be directly accessible from Azure Portal